# Consecutive stmfd sp!, {lr} and ldmfd sp!, {lr} instructions in Linux kernel functions

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, linux-kernel, arm

While examining the ARM assembly of some functions within the Linux kernel, I noticed a pattern where two instructions consistently appear consecutively near the beginning:

```
stmfd sp!, {lr}
ldmfd sp!, {lr}
```

e.g., `vfs_write`:

```
0xc03741d4 <vfs_write>: push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r11, lr}
0xc03741d8 <vfs_write+4>:       add     r11, sp, #24
0xc03741dc <vfs_write+8>:       sub     sp, sp, #96     ; 0x60
0xc03741e0 <vfs_write+12>:      mov     r4, r0
0xc03741e4 <vfs_write+16>:      movw    r0, #25800      ; 0x64c8
0xc03741e8 <vfs_write+20>:      movt    r0, #49472      ; 0xc140
0xc03741ec <vfs_write+24>:      mov     r8, r3
0xc03741f0 <vfs_write+28>:      ldr     r0, [r0]
0xc03741f4 <vfs_write+32>:      mov     r5, r2
0xc03741f8 <vfs_write+36>:      mov     r7, r1
0xc03741fc <vfs_write+40>:      str     r0, [r11, #-28] ; 0xffffffe4
0xc0374200 <vfs_write+44>:      stmfd   sp!, {lr}
0xc0374204 <vfs_write+48>:      ldmfd   sp!, {lr}
0xc0374208 <vfs_write+52>:      ldr     r0, [r4, #40]   ; 0x28
0xc037420c <vfs_write+56>:      mvn     r6, #8
0xc0374210 <vfs_write+60>:      tst     r0, #2
```

This seems a bit puzzling as the first instruction pushes the `lr` onto the stack, and the very next one immediately pops it off. I haven't checked every single function, but this seems to be a recurring pattern in the ones I've looked at.

Is there a specific reason or architectural rationale behind this in the context of the Linux kernel? Or could these consecutive instructions be considered redundant?

Comment: Do you have debug symbols for the kernel that could associate each instruction with a source line?  But that's all before the first branch but an early-out `if` is the first thing `vfs_write` does: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.4.11/source/fs/read_write.c#L564  - that's the `ldr r0, [r4, #40]`  / `tst r0, #2` checking `if (!(file->f_mode & FMODE_WRITE))` I assume.  So this is all before that.

Comment: Can you add more info about the kernel you are looking at? Kernel version + exact arch + endiannes + build config?

Comment: @PeteRiches - Your edit to the title is not at all what this question was asking about.  There's no reason to expect those `stmfd   sp!, {lr}` / `ldmfd` instructions are related to parameter passing; we can see the earlier part of the prologue saving the incoming `r0`, `r1`, `r2`, and `r3` to call-preserved registers it's already `push`ed, e.g. with `mov  r4, r0`, so it can keep them across later calls to other functions.  The ARM calling convention (first 4 integer/pointer args in R0-R3) doesn't explain this `stmfd`/ `ldmfd` at all. I'm rolling back the title edit but keeping the improvements